# Java based Wiki Engine

Tags: java, wiki

I am trying to review the different available wiki engines and was interested in one that is java based. Could you recommend or list any java based wiki engine so that i can have check it out.

I am familiar with the following JSPWIKi, Elsie.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using JSPWiki since a few years.

[JSPWiki](http://www.jspwiki.org/) is a feature-rich and extensible WikiWiki  engine built around the standard J2EE components (Java, servlets, JSP).

Answer (score 8):

There are quite a few available.  [I'd check out the open-source ones first](http://java-source.net/open-source/wiki-engines).

I have to say [XWiki impressed me most](http://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome), but that was for a feature set we were looking for quite a while ago, it may not match your exact needs...check out the full list I linked, see if anything fits you well.

Answer (score 3):

You might like to think about [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/). It's not open source, but it's [extensible](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+Developer+Documentation), if you wanted to make some kind of plugin.

Answer (score 1):

[VQWiki](http://www.vqwiki.org/) and [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) have worked well for us.

Answer (score 1):

Another great Java based Wiki engine is GWiki http://labs.micromata.de/display/gwiki/Home it can be embedded and extended by macros written in in Java or Groovy.